# ShellExecute('open','cmd.exe',SW_HIDE); А как Закрыть!?

Tags: delphi

```
ShellExecute(0,'open','cmd.exe','/k ipconfig /flushdns', pchar(sysdir+'\system32\'),SW_HIDE);
```

А как после этого правильно закрыть cmd.exe? в процессах он остается висеть после выполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная функция (ShellExecute) возвращает число более 32, если выполнение успешно, иначе - код возникшей ошибки. **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Вы можете искать открытое вами приложение, используя энумератор процессов. Но, кажется, я знаю, что вам нужно сделать. Вы пытаетесь выполнить консольную команду в фоне, но у вас этого незаметно сделать не получается. В таком случае просто откройте `cmd.exe с параметром /с` - в таком случае консоль сразу же закроется сама после выполнения команды.

Comment: Отлично, работает. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста =)